# How to read parquet files from AWS S3 with polars

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-polars

Following the [documentation](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/io/cloud-storage/#reading-from-cloud-storage) for reading from cloud storage, I have created the below script that fails.

```py
import boto3
import polars as pl
import os

session = boto3.Session(profile_name=os.environ["AWS_PROFILE"])
credentials = session.get_credentials()
current_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()
# Specify your S3 bucket and file path
s3_bucket = "bucket"
s3_file_path = "path/file.parquet"

# Create the full S3 path
s3_path = f"s3://{s3_bucket}/{s3_file_path}"

storage_options = {
    'aws_access_key_id': current_credentials.access_key,
    'aws_secret_access_key': current_credentials.secret_key,
    'aws_region': 'us-east-1' credentials
}

df = pl.scan_parquet(s3_path, storage_options=storage_options)
```

This gives output below which I understand is a common error for not having permissions to access the file.

> ComputeError: Generic S3 error: Client error with status 403 Forbidden: No Body

versions:

- Python '3.9.18'
- polars '0.20.14'
- boto3 '1.34.58'

Running on macos.

I am also successfully able to read the parquet using pandas just setting the AWS_PROFILE env var.

Am I using the storage_options incorrectly? It doesn't seem able to take 'aws_profile' key value pair to extract local config credentials its self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also need to pass the corresponding session token as follows.

```
import polars as pl
import boto3

profile_name = "your-profile"
s3_path = "s3://my-s3-bucket/my_file.parquet"

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()

df = pl.read_parquet(
    s3_path,
    storage_options={
        "aws_access_key_id": credentials.access_key,
        "aws_secret_access_key": credentials.secret_key,
        "aws_session_token": credentials.token,
        "aws_region": session.region_name,
    },
)
```

From the [AWS access keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/feature-static-credentials.html) documentation:

> Specifies an AWS session token used as part of the credentials to authenticate the user. You receive this value as part of the temporary credentials returned by successful requests to assume a role. A session token is required only if you manually specify temporary security credentials. However, we recommend you always use temporary security credentials instead of long-term credentials. For security recommendations, see [Security best practices in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html).

Comment: Thanks this works. If you know if there is any documentation for possible values for the storage_options argument that would be useful. Could not find anything myself.

Comment: @DataJack Under a link titled "aws" next to `storage_options`, the documentation for [pl.read_parquet](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_parquet.html) mentions that the supported keys are listed in the [object store](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/aws/enum.AmazonS3ConfigKey.html) documentation.

Comment: how did my brains scroll past that! Thanks.